# Some time the prgram runs some time it crashes in C

Tags: c

I made this program in c, but some time it works and run perfectly and sometimes it doesn't anyone can help me with it?

The program is in Portuguese, sorry if this is a problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char nome[40];
    char tel[15];
    char email[40];
    char status[2];
    int tipo;
} cadeiras;
```

This first function is the Menu

```
void menu()
{ // Menu inicial do programa.
    printf("MENU PRINCIPAL \n\n");
    printf("1 - Visualizar mapa do teatro\n");
    printf("2 - Comprar cadeira\n");
    printf("3 - Reservar cadeira\n");
    printf("4 - Consultar uma determinada cadeira da Sala\n");
    printf("5 - Total arrecado\n");
    printf("6 - Sair do Aplicativo\n");
    printf("Digite o numero de uma das opcoes acima: ");
}
```

This function changes a number in to a leter.

```
void letranumero(int numero) 
{
    switch (numero)
    {
    case 0:
        printf("A");
        break;
    case 1:
        printf("B");
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("C");
        break;
    case 3:
        printf("D");
        break;
    case 4:
        printf("E");
        break;
    case 5:
        printf("F");
        break;
    case 6:
        printf("G");
        break;
    case 7:
        printf("H");
        break;
    case 8:
        printf("I");
        break;
    case 9:
        printf("J");
        break;
    case 10:
        printf("K");
        break;
    case 11:
        printf("L");
        break;
    case 12:
        printf("M");
        break;
    case 13:
        printf("N");
        break;
    case 14:
        printf("O");
        break;
    case 15:
        printf("P");
        break;
    case 16:
        printf("Q");
        break;
    case 17:
        printf("R");
        break;
    case 18:
        printf("S");
        break;
    case 19:
        printf("T");
        break;
    case 20:
        printf("U");
        break;
    case 21:
        printf("V");
        break;
    case 22:
        printf("W");
        break;
    case 23:
        printf("X");
        break;
    case 24:
        printf("Y");
        break;
    case 25:
        printf("Z");
        break;
    }
}
```

This function is the opposite of the last one. It changes a letter in to number.

```
void numeroletra(char letra, int *n) // Transforma a letra de uma fileira digitada em um numero.
{
    switch (letra)
    {
    case 'A':
        *n = 0;
        break;
    case 'B':
        *n = 1;
        break;
    case 'C':
        *n = 2;
        break;
    case 'D':
        *n = 3;
        break;
    case 'E':
        *n = 4;
        break;
    case 'F':
        *n = 5;
        break;
    case 'G':
        *n = 6;
        break;
    case 'H':
        *n = 7;
        break;
    case 'I':
        *n = 8;
        break;
    case 'J':
        *n = 9;
        break;
    case 'K':
        *n = 10;
        break;
    case 'L':
        *n = 11;
        break;
    case 'M':
        *n = 12;
        break;
    case 'N':
        *n = 13;
        break;
    case 'O':
        *n = 14;
        break;
    case 'P':
        *n = 15;
        break;
    case 'Q':
        *n = 16;
        break;
    case 'R':
        *n = 17;
        break;
    case 'S':
        *n = 18;
        break;
    case 'T':
        *n = 19;
        break;
    case 'U':
        *n = 20;
        break;
    case 'V':
        *n = 21;
        break;
    case 'W':
        *n = 22;
        break;
    case 'X':
        *n = 23;
        break;
    case 'Y':
        *n = 24;
        break;
    case 'Z':
        *n = 25;
        break;
    }
}
```

This function is to make te matrix have zeros.

```
void zerar(cadeiras cadeira[21][29])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 22; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 30; j++)
        {
            strcpy(cadeira[i][j].nome, " ");
            strcpy(cadeira[i][j].tel, " ");
            strcpy(cadeira[i][j].email, " ");
            strcpy(cadeira[i][j].status, "L");
            cadeira[i][j].tipo = 0;
        }
}
```

This is the main function. It's supose to be a ticket office of theater.

```
int main()
{
    cadeiras cadeira[21][29];
    int i, j, op, controle;
    char aux;
    if (controle != 1)
    {
        zerar(cadeira);
        controle = 1;
    }
    printf("  ******* T E A T R O ******* \n");
    do
    {
        menu();
        scanf("%d", &op);
        printf("\n");

        switch (op)
        {
        case 1:
            for (i = 0; i < 22; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < 15; j++)
                {
                    letranumero(i);
                    printf("%d-", j + 1);
                    printf("%s ", cadeira[i][j].status);
                }

                printf("        ");

                for (j = 15; j < 30; j++)
                {
                    letranumero(i);
                    printf("%d-", j + 1);
                    printf("%s ", cadeira[i][j].status);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            printf("Digite fileira da cadeira que deseja comprar: ");
            scanf(" %c", &aux);
            numeroletra(aux, &i);
            printf("Digite coluna da cadeira que deseja comprar: ");
            scanf("%d", &j);
            j--;
            if (cadeira[i][j].status[0] == 'L')
            {
                printf("Digite o nome do cliente: ");
                fgets(cadeira[i][j].nome, 40, stdin);
                printf("Digite o telefone do cliente: ");
                fgets(cadeira[i][j].tel, 15, stdin);
                printf("Digite o email do cliente: ");
                fgets(cadeira[i][j].email, 40, stdin);
                printf("Digite 1 pra Meia e 2 para Inteira: ");
                scanf("%d", &cadeira[i][j].tipo);
                if (cadeira[i][j].tipo != 1 && cadeira[i][j].tipo != 2)
                {
                    do
                    {
                        printf("Tipo invalido, digite 1 pra Meia e 2 para Inteira: ");
                        scanf("%d", &cadeira[i][j].tipo);
                    } while (cadeira[i][j].tipo != 1 && cadeira[i][j].tipo != 2);
                }

                strcpy(cadeira[i][j].status, "O");
                printf("Cadeira comprada com sucesso!\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Cadeira ja esta ocupada!\n");
            }
            break;

        case 3:
            printf("Digite fileira da cadeira que deseja reservar: ");
            scanf(" %c", &aux);
            numeroletra(aux, &i);
            printf("Digite coluna da cadeira que deseja reservar: ");
            scanf("%d", &j);
            j--;
            if (cadeira[i][j].status[0] == 'L')
            {
                printf("Digite o nome do cliente: ");
                fgets(cadeira[i][j].nome, 40, stdin);
                printf("Digite o telefone do cliente: ");
                fgets(cadeira[i][j].tel, 15, stdin);
                printf("Digite o email do cliente: ");
                fgets(cadeira[i][j].email, 40, stdin);
                printf("Digite 1 pra Meia e 2 para Inteira: ");
                scanf("%d", &cadeira[i][j].tipo);
                if (cadeira[i][j].tipo != 1 && cadeira[i][j].tipo != 2)
                {
                    do
                    {
                        printf("Tipo invalido, digite 1 pra Meia e 2 para Inteira: ");
                        scanf("%d", &cadeira[i][j].tipo);
                    } while (cadeira[i][j].tipo != 1 && cadeira[i][j].tipo != 2);
                }

                strcpy(cadeira[i][j].status, "R");
                printf("Cadeira reservada com sucesso!\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Cadeira ja esta ocupada!\n");
            }
            break;
        }

        printf("\n");
    } while (op != 6);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger.

Comment: You're absolutely breaching the `cadeira` array of arrays in `main`. The array is decalred as `[21][29]`. the `zerar` function iterates on over `0 < i < 22` and `0 < j < 30`, triggering *undefined behavior*. And this happens in *multiple* places in your code. Review how to index arrays in C.

Comment: What @Blindyis talking about: `void numeroletra(char letra, int *n) { if (letra >= 'A' && letra <= 'Z') *m = letra - 'A'; }`

Answer (score 1):

Your program has multiple problems:

- In `main()` the variable `controle` is uninitialized, so the `if` statement

```
if (controle != 1) { 
     zerar(cadeira); 
     controle = 1; 
}
```

Leads to undefined behaviour.

- In various parts of your `main()` function you don't check what `scanf()` returns, for example on the line

```
scanf("%d", &op);
```

This can be especially dangerous if invalid data is entered. Instead you should check what `scanf()` returns, for example:

```
if (scanf("%d", &op) != 1)
{
     // error procedure
}
```

- In your `zerar()` function  your loops go out of bounds when using `strcpy` to append to the array. Instead of using the conditions `i < 22` and `j < 30` it should be `i < 21` and `j < 29`.

It should look like this:

```
void zerar(cadeiras cadeira[21][29]) { 

           int i, j; 
           for (i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
                  for (j = 0; j < 29; j++) {   

                       strcpy(cadeira[i][j].nome, " ");   
                       strcpy(cadeira[i][j].tel, " ");                     
                       strcpy(cadeira[i][j].email, " ");   
                       strcpy(cadeira[i][j].status, "L"); 
                       cadeira[i][j].tipo = 0; 
                  }
            }
```

- In your `main ()` function you have multiple loops which go out of bounds which leads to more undefined behaviour.
- As a result of invalid array indexes being used in your code, various `strcpy()` calls also become dangerous and could lead to segmentation faults or undefined behaviour.